Can't run a window on the second X session
I use Ubuntu 20.04. In order to run a second X session I switch to tty3 (ctrl + alt + f3), log in and execute the following command:
startx openbox -- :2

I would like to open a window on the second X session from my default X session. I switch back to tty2, open a gnome terminal and execute the following commands:
export DISPLAY=:2
xterm

Then I get the following error:
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyxterm: Xt error: Can't open display: :2

How to fix that ?
